# Google Chrome can't start

Tags: google-chrome

I installed Google Chrome on my Ubuntu Server 18.04 from a Debian package. I ran `google-chrome` to start Chrome and got the following errors:

```
[1130/114916.661240:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[1130/114916.661550:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Comment: Where did you install it from Ubuntu software, apt repository or Debian package?

Comment: a debian package

Comment: Ubuntu server doesn't have a GUI

Comment: This ^^^ Any graphical software need a GUI.